# Documentformat.openxml - create word document with default styles

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I want the word document created to use the default styles in Word, so the user can change the styles using the built in themes.

I have tried using:

```
        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        var run = new Run();
        run.Append(new Text(text));
        paragraph.Append(run);
        var header = new Header();
        header.Append(paragraph);
```

But its styled as "Normal".

So, how do i make it become "Heading 1" when i open the document in Word?

Comment: `Normal` is the default style. What are you asking?

Comment: I was thinking about "Heading 1", "Title", etc. I found a way to do it, by reflecting a template document, and adding the styles manually in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're like me and you found this post because you were trying to build documents using OpenXML with the default styles "Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Title", etc. you get when you use Microsoft Word I found the solution after a few hours.

First I tried to find the styles in the normal template "Normal.dotm". This is not where the styles are stored, you are looking in the wrong place. The default styles are actually defined in a "Default.dotx" file in a directory named QuickStyles.

The path is going to change depending on your version and your OS. For me I found the dotx at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1033\QuickStyles".

I found some code from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/02/18/how-to-create-a-document-from-a-template-dotx-dotm-and-attach-to-it-using-open-xml-sdk.aspx) to create and modify a document from a template:

```
void CreateWordDocumentUsingMSWordStyles(string outputPath, string templatePath)
{
    // create a copy of the template and open the copy
    System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, outputPath, true);

    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
    {
        document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

        var mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
        var settings = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart;

        var templateRelationship = new AttachedTemplate { Id = "relationId1" };
        settings.Settings.Append(templateRelationship);

        var templateUri = new Uri("c:\\anything.dotx", UriKind.Absolute); // you can put any path you like and the document styles still work
        settings.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate", templateUri, templateRelationship.Id);

        // using Title as it would appear in Microsoft Word
        var paragraphProps = new ParagraphProperties();
        paragraphProps.ParagraphStyleId = new ParagraphStyleId { Val = "Title" };

        // add some text with the "Title" style from the "Default" style set supplied by Microsoft Word
        var run = new Run();
        run.Append(new Text("My Title!"));

        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Append(paragraphProps);
        paragraph.Append(run);

        mainPart.Document.Body.Append(paragraph);

        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

Simply call this method with templatePath pointing to your Default.dotx file and you will be able to use the default styles as they appear in Microsoft Word.

```
var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();

CreateWordDocumentUsingMSWordStyles(path, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\1033\\QuickStyles\\Default.dotx");
```

This does let the user change "Style Sets" in Word once they open the document as per the original question.

Comment: I did not have the option of adding templates on the server, however i solved it using reflection on a word document, and adding the generated code to my code. I would have to say your way is neater, since you can just replace templates if you want it to look differently by default.

Comment: @ruffen can you please post the code you actually use as an answer to your own question?

Comment: @SandRock unfortunatelly I cannot as this work was done for a client I was at the time and I dont have access to the code anymore. If I remember correctly I used a 3rd part software to give me the reflected code and copied that into my software manually.